# apex:pageBlockTable fixed number of rows

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable

I've set my apex:pageBlockTable 'rows' attribute to 10 but it is collapsed when there are less than 10 records in the table. Is there a way to keep the number of rows fixed? Or will I have to switch to pure HTML table?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add empty objects to the collection that the table is displaying (assuming you have a controller). Using `Contact` as an example and assuming `<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!rows}" ...>`

```
public Contact[] getRows() {
    Contact[] rows = [select Name from Contact limit 4];
    for (Integer i = rows.size(); i < 10; i++) {
        rows.add(new Contact());
    }
    return rows;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Keith! I  ended up mixing your solution with html table + apex:repeat for its rows.